# Conditional Expectation of nested sigma algebra

Tags: measure-theory, conditional-expectation, solution-verification

Consider the sample space $\Omega = \{\omega_{i}\}_{i=1}^{3}$
with $ω_{i}$ are independent identically distributed according
to,

$ω_{i} = 1$ with probability $0.5$

$ω_{i} = −1$ with probability $0.5$

Furthermore, define $X_{n}(\omega) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}{\omega_{i}}$
and let $\mathcal{F_{1}} = \sigma(X_{1}), \mathcal{F_{12}} = σ({\omega_{1}, \omega_{2}})$ (the sigma algebras
generated by the outcome of the first flip and of the first two flips respectively). Compute

a) $\mathbb{E}[X_{3}|X_{1}]$

b) $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X_{3}|\mathcal{F_{1}}]|\mathcal{F_{12}}]$

c) $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X_{3}|\mathcal{F_{12}}]|\mathcal{F_{1}}]$

d) Check that the answer to the above two points is the same.

$\textbf{My Attempt (Edited)}$

a) $\mathbb{E}[X_{3}|X_{1}] = \mathbb{E}[X_{1}+X_{2}+X_{3}|X_{1}] = X_{1} \mathbb{E}[X_{2}+X_{3}|X_{1}] = X_{1}\mathbb{E}[X_{2}+X_{3}] = 0$

b) $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X_{3}|\mathcal{F_{1}}]|\mathcal{F_{12}}]$

Let $Z=\mathbb{E}[X_{3}|\mathcal{F_{1}}]$. We know that,

$\mathbb{E}[X_{3}|\omega_{1}=1] = \mathbb{E}[\omega_{1} + \omega_{2} + \omega_{3}|\omega_{1}=1] = 1 + \mathbb{E}[\omega_{2} + \omega_{3}|\omega_{1}=1]= 1$

$\mathbb{E}[X_{3}|\omega_{1}= -1] = \mathbb{E}[\omega_{1} + \omega_{2} + \omega_{3}|\omega_{1}=-1] = -1 + \mathbb{E}[\omega_{2} + \omega_{3}|\omega_{1}=-1]= -1$

So, Z = $X_{1}$ and $\mathbb{E}[Z|\mathcal{F_{12}}]= X_{1}$ since $X_{1}$ is $\mathcal{F_{12}}$ measurable.

c) $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X_{3}|\mathcal{F_{12}}]|\mathcal{F_{1}}]$

We know that, $\mathcal{F_{1}} \subset \mathcal{F_{12}}$, so by the tower property,

$\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X_{3}|\mathcal{F_{12}}]|\mathcal{F_{1}}] = \mathbb{E}[X_{3}|\mathcal{F_{1}}] = Z = X_{1}$.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Just as a remark, I think what you defined is not a sample space, but rather a collection of random variables. The natural sample space you seem to work with is $\Omega= \{ -1,1 \}^3$ with the power set as the sigma algebra.

Comment: $a+b+c\neq a(b+c)$ both times.

Comment: @aa777 in part a it should be $\mathbb{E}[X_{3}|X_{1}] = \mathbb{E}[X_{1}+X_{2}+X_{3}|X_{1}] = X_{1} \color{red}{+}\mathbb{E}[X_{2}+X_{3}|X_{1}] $ (look red $\color{red}{+}$, you used * instead +) (as NCH mentioned)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According what I think I make a little change to clear the question.

$$\Omega=\{ (1,1,1),(1,1,-1),(1,-1,-1),(1,-1,1),
(-1,1,1),(-1,1,-1),(-1,-1,-1),(-1,-1,1)
\}$$
when $(1,1,1)$ means $(\omega_1=1,\omega_2=1,\omega_3=1)$ .

so

\begin{eqnarray}
\begin{array}{c|ccc}
     &(1,1,1)&(1,1,-1)&(1,-1,-1)&(1,-1,1)&
(-1,1,1)&(-1,1,-1)&(-1,-1,-1)& (-1,-1,1) \\ \hline
X_1    &  1  &  1  &  1  &   1  &   -1  &  -1  &  -1  &   -1  \\ 
X_2    &  2  &  2  &  0  &   0  &  0 & 0 & -2 & -2  \\
X_3    &  3  &  1  &  -1  &   1  &  1 & -1 &-3 & -1  \\
\end{array}
\end{eqnarray}

Part a)
$$E(X_3|X_1)= E(\omega_1 + \omega_2 + \omega_3|\omega_1)
=\omega_1 + E( \omega_2 + \omega_3|\omega_1)$$
$$=\omega_1 + E( \omega_2 + \omega_3)=\omega_1 + 0=X_1$$

In part $b$ and $c$ i use [Tower property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Basic_properties)  
lets $F_1$ and $F_2$ are two sigma field such that $F_1\subset F_2$ so
$$E(E(X|F_1)|F_2)=E(E(X|F_2)|F_1)=E(X|F_1)$$

part b)

$$\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X_{3}|\mathcal{F_{1}}]|\mathcal{F_{12}}]=
E\bigg(E\color{red}{\big(}X_3|\sigma(\omega_1)\color{red}{\big)}|\sigma(\omega_1,\omega_2)\bigg)
\overset{Tower.p}{=}E\color{red}{\big(}X_3|\sigma(\omega_1)\color{red}{\big)}=\omega_1$$
in $\overset{Tower.p}{=}$ equation since $\sigma(\omega_1)\subset \sigma(\omega_1,\omega_2)$ i used
Tower property. part $c$ is similar.

we can handle it without Tower property. for example part $b$

$$E(X_3|\sigma(\omega_1))=E(X_3|\{\omega_1=1\}) 1_{\{\omega_1=1\}} +
E(X_3|\{\omega_1=-1\}) 1_{\{\omega_1=-1\}}
$$
$$=(1) 1_{\{\omega_1=1\}} +
(-1) 1_{\{\omega_1=-1\}}= 1_{\{\omega_1=1\}} -1_{\{\omega_1=-1\}}=w_1
$$

so

$$E\bigg(E\color{red}{\big(}X_3|\sigma(\omega_1)\color{red}{\big)}|\sigma(\omega_1,\omega_2)\bigg)
=E\bigg(w_1|\sigma(\omega_1,\omega_2)\bigg)=w_1$$